# CircleCI permission denied opening firebase-tools.json for Firebase deployment

Tags: firebase, yaml, firebase-hosting, circleci, firebase-cli

I'm using Firebase to host my personal website and wanted to integrate CircleCI for faster integration. However I receive this error on the step for deployment:

**Note**
Adding sudo before the deploy command causes the build to fail also

```
/home/circleci/project/node_modules/configstore/index.js:52
          throw error;
          ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/circleci/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

Below is my project's yaml configuration:

```
---
commands:
  restore_cache_cmd:
    description: "Restore cached npm install"
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          key: 'dependency-cache-{{checksum "package.json"}}'
  save_cache_cmd:
    description: "Saving npm install"
    steps:
      - save_cache:
          key: 'dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json"}}'
          paths:
            - "./node_modules"
  update:
    description: "Installing project's dependencies"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache_cmd
      - run: sudo npm i -g npm@latest
      - run: sudo npm i
      - save_cache_cmd
  build_deploy:
    description: "Building project"
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: sudo npm run build
      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_DEPLOY_TOKEN -- only hosting
executors:
  docker-executor:
    docker:
      - image: "cimg/node:12.14.1"
jobs:
  build_site:
    executor: docker-executor
    working_directory: ~/Darryls-Personal-Site
    steps:
      - update
      - build_deploy
version: 2.1
workflows:
  build_site:
    jobs:
      - build_site:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Steps that I have already completed from other questions:

- Used firebase login:ci to obtain refresh token and placed into an environment variable within my CircleCI project environment
- Used npm install --save-dev firebase-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you run all your `npm` commands with `sudo` except the `firebase deploy` command.
You should definitely run everything with the current user and not the superuser.
You will see in [official tutorials](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/node) that nothing is run with `sudo` except for very specific cases.

Also, instead of doing this `./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy` you could use `npx run firebase deploy` which first look in the local `node_modules` then in the global ones.